# IDEA ERROR : Built-in server is disabled by `idea.builtin.server.disabled`

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have installed intellJ, community edition. And every time i try and run any program it gives me a weird build error saying:

> java.lang.Throwable: Built-in server is disabled by
> `idea.builtin.server.disabled` VM option

[image]

Has anyone faced this error before? My idea version is 2020.2

Answer (score 0):

Check Help | Edit Custom VM Options for `-Didea.builtin.server.disabled=true` and Help | Edit Custom Properties for `idea.builtin.server.disabled=true`. Remove this line.